# Remove whitespace in for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, whitespace

I've made a simple script in python which shifts the letters up 5 spaces in the ASCII table using chr and ord. See below:

```
word = "python"

print 'Shifted 5 letters are: '
for letters in word:    
    print chr(ord(letters)+5),
```

The output is:

```
Shifted 5 letters is: 
u ~ y m t s
```

The output is great, but how do I stop the for loop putting spaces in-between each letter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't need to use the for loop, simply do this:

```
print ''.join([chr(ord(letter) + 5) for letter in word])
```

instead of the whole loop.

Comment: Thanks, that works but how is it working? What is the thing I need to read about? Is it string manipulation? thanks

Comment: [This](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) should give you the information about the `''.join`, and [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for the rest of it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to stop Python 2.x's `print` statement from printing a space when you use the "magic comma".

This is part of the reason Python 3.x's `print` function is more flexible, using keyword arguments instead of magic syntax:

```
for letters in word:    
    print(chr(ord(letters)+5), end='')
```

If you really want to, you can get the same behavior in Python 2.x with `from __future__ import print_function` (or by using the third-party `six` library).

However, usually, when you're having problem fighting with `print` to do what you want, the solution is to format your string first, then print it. So:

```
output = ''
for letters in word:
    output += chr(ord(letters)+5)
print output
```

It's generally more pythonic (and faster) to build up a `list` of strings, and calling [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) at the end, instead of repeatedly appending to a string:

```
output = []
for letters in word:
    output.append(chr(ord(letters)+5))
print ''.join(output)
```

And you can make that simpler (and even more fasterer) by turning the loop into a [comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of a statement:

```
print ''.join(chr(ord(letters) + 5) for letters in word)
```

Comment: By the way, I used a generator expression instead of a list comprehension because, it makes more conceptual sense to feed `join` an iterator. (Of course under the covers, `join` is just going to call `list` on it, but I wouldn't expect everyone to have that in the front of their mind, so unless the small performance difference makes a difference, I think the iterator is clearer.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I get what you're asking 100 % but this work-around returned the letters without any whitespace :

```
def no_space(word) :
new_word = ""
for letter in word :
    new_word += chr(ord(letter) + 5)
return new_word
```

Then call the function :

```
no_space("python")
```

Result : 'u~ymts'